# Android studio has stopped my project with an error execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'

Tags: android, android-studio

**I run my android project, everything is correct and an error comes to say execution failed for task as shown on details.**

**Details :**

*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'. > Exception while doing past iteration backup : Source C:\Users\Abdulwahid\AndroidStudioProjects\More1Activity\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\13727462725703\classes.dex and destination C:\Users\Abdulwahid\AndroidStudioProjects\More1Activity\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\13727462725703\classes.dex must be different*

Comment: I don't know what classes.dex means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just need to rebuild the project.